# Functional-Programming exception-processing style with Spring-Integration

Tags: functional-programming, spring-integration-dsl

How to implement a functional-programming style of exception-processing with Spring-Integration ?
i.e. instead of letting the exception bubble up to the caller or to send it down to a dedicated message-channel, have the error-prone component (e.g. gateway, router etc...) wrap the result/exception with a Option/Either construct and continue to process the rest of the integration-flow.
For example if my integration-flow looks like below, how to wrap the gateway component to pass an Either<Throwable,Object> to the following transformer ?

```
IntegrationFlows  
.from(someChannel)
.gateway(someGateway)
.transform(someTransformer)
.log()
.get()
```

Subsidiary question: what do you think are the drawbacks of such approach ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your expertise and your time.
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an [`ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain) (or a custom advice) to each endpoint.

```
.gateway(..., e -> e.advice(myAdvice))
```